# How does the order of implementation of Generative Data Augmentation and Generative Audio Super-Resoln matter? Which one should be implemented first?

Tags: generative-models, data-augmentation

I have a low quality audio dataset that I will use for classification. My goal is both to increase the quality of this dataset to make it easier to label it with supervised methods (super resolution) and to increase the number of data in the dataset so that it can be used in training and testing (data augmentation). For both method, generative models are currently state-of-the art. Without trying, I am theoretically curious.

How do you predict the effects of the order in which these two processes are applied to the raw data?
Raw Data->Super Resolution -> Data Augmentation or
Raw Data-> Data Augmentation -> Super Resolution?